# React.js Circular slider with two thumbs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slider, circular-slider

I am trying to build a circular slider with two thumbs(knobs). The requirement is very specific our client wants it to be circular in shape and should have two knobs .I tried changing the shape of MUISlider to circular(already supports two knobs not circular though) but in vain.

https://codesandbox.io/s/h0esn

We tried this but doesnt support two knobs - https://dmitrymorozoff.github.io/react-circle-slider/

Please find attached image for refrence help me in finding something that suits our requirement .
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the [roundSlider](https://roundsliderui.com/) plugin which supports lots of customization. Check the below demo for the circular slider with two thumbs example:

#### Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-circular-slider-with-two-thumbs